# C# sql related exception

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to do a simple C# windows application as a beginner. But I get a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`. When I try to connect to database it says connection is OK. But it doesn't allow me to create any tables using visual studio. I can't figure out why it doesn't show options to add new table.
Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace best
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {

      SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Janith Kularathne\Documents\testing.mdf;
        Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void insertB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into details values('"+ idBox.Text +"', '"+ nameBox.Text + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        idBox.Text = "";
        nameBox.Text="";
        DisplayDetails();
        MessageBox.Show("Insertion succesfull");           
    }

    private void deleteB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Delete from details where id= '" + idBox.Text + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        idBox.Text = "";
        nameBox.Text = "";
        DisplayDetails();
        MessageBox.Show("delete succesfull");
    }

    private void updateB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "update details set id, name,category where  id= '" + idBox.Text + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        idBox.Text = "";
        nameBox.Text = "";
        DisplayDetails();
        MessageBox.Show("Update succesfull");
    }

    private void searchB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "selet *from details where  id= '" + idBox.Text + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        DisplayDetails();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayDetails();
    }

    public void DisplayDetails()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from details";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when I type `0';   Drop table Details ; ` into `idBox` ?

Answer (score 6):

Your code currently contains a variety of different issues, which I'll elaborate a bit on and should resolve some of your current problems :

- Unnecessary closing parentheses
- Typos and Misspellings
- Incorrect Syntax
- Using Parameterization

In addition to these, I'd highly recommend reading through some tutorials on using the different methods like `ExecuteNonQuery()`, `ExecuteReader()` and `ExecuteNonScalar()` to determine how to actual retrieve values from your queries once you execute them.

**Unnecessary Closing Parentheses**

You currently have a trailing closing parentheses within each of your queries which is likely causing a syntax error within your `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` queries :

```
// Notice the unnecessary trailing ')', which should only be useful within your INSERT call
cmd.CommandText = "..." + idBox.Text + "')";
```

**Typos and Misspellings**

An additional typo is present within your search query as well as the word "SELECT" is misspelled:

```
// "selet" should be "Select"
cmd.CommandText = "selet *from details where  id= '" + idBox.Text + "')";
```

**Incorrect Syntax**

Your current `UPDATE` query doesn't actually appear to be doing anything. You are using the `SET` keyword, but aren't actually setting the values to anything :

```
// UPDATE queries should be in the form UPDATE {table} SET {Column} = {Value} WHERE ...
cmd.CommandText = "update details set id, name,category where id= '" + idBox.Text + "')";
```

**Parameterization, Not Concatenation**

Additionally, you should really consider using parameterization when building your queries. It can help avoid nastiness like SQL Injection and prevent syntax errors as well.

You can see an example of what this might look like for one of your methods below :

```
private void searchB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    var query = "SELECT * FROM details WHERE ID = @id";
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",idBox.Text);
         using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
               // Access your results here and do something with them
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have just flagged the post as offtopic and force the user to make his own homework instead of providing him the answer to these errors?

Comment: Fair point. If this is OP's work however, then he/she clearly tried to implement these and ran into various types of errors. I'm just chiming in on some of the things that were done wrong and how they might be remedied.

Comment: Since this is using pass through queries I would suggest not using AddWithValue. It can sometimes get datatypes wrong. It is better in this case to use explicitly typed parameters. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @Sean, that's a good point and worth mentioning. I simply used `AddWithValue()` out of convenience / brevity.